# Test for statistical significance between the mean of a sample and a number

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have 20-30 repeated measurements each of which produce a single number. My goal is to determine whether the mean of these numbers is statistically significantly greater than the number 1. (significantly less than 1 does not count, in this case)

I know, for example, that if I want to know whether the means of two populations are different, I can use a t-test, but this does not seem to apply when one of my "populations" is just the fixed number 1. Can anyone help suggest the correct test?

Comment: If you're prepared to assume independence (which may be doubtful with repeated measures) and common variance, and that the population is (sufficiently close to) normally distributed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test

Comment: Erika was first, so I accepted their answer, but yes -- an upper tailed one-sample t-test is exactly what I'm looking for. @Glen_b I actually can assume independence in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a ***One-Sample T-test***.
This site explains the procedure and also has a working example -
http://www.biostathandbook.com/onesamplettest.html

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a one-sample t-test, as mentioned by Erika.

You can use the calculator here (and the information below the calculator for reference):
https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/t-distribution.aspx

Make sure you select sample, in place of t-score.